# Add accuracy to data frame based on several predicted values and known actual values

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
testdf <- data.frame(predicted1 = c(1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), predicted2 = c(1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), predicted3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), actual = c(1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0))
```

I want to add another column to this data frame which tells me the total percentage accuracy when looking at all predicted values. So for example, row 1 of this would have an accuracy of 100%, because all prediction columns predicted the correct value (1).

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can compare with the 'actual' get the `rowMeans`, multiply by 100 and `round` if needed

```
round(100*rowMeans(testdf[1:3] == testdf$actual), 2)
```